# How does code produced on an open-source framework is affected by it's original license (MIT in this case)

Tags: licensing, open-source, frameworks, laravel

I'm looking into building a new PHP commercial app for a client that will be hosted as a paid service and possibly resold to third parties with a non-compete clause.

I've tested a few frameworks and chose Laravel which is licensed under the MIT License. The framework itself will not be modified but the app will be heavily dependent on Laravel functions and architecture.

How does the original license affects code produced with the software it's covering? MIT being a non-viral license, my humble guess is that my code can be distributed under a more commercial-friendly license that prevent third-parties to do anything else than using the app as a final product as long as the original licensed is kept for the framework part.

Am I wrong? How should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Wikipedia explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License):

> It is a permissive free software license, meaning that it permits reuse within proprietary software provided all copies of the licensed software include a copy of the MIT License terms and the copyright notice. Such proprietary software retains its proprietary nature even though it incorporates software under the MIT License.

Comment: Does this mean if he sells his PHP app to a third party he could restrict them from reselling the stuff that he created, but he can not prevent them for selling just the Laravel code, because Laravel is under MIT?